# JSON Schema forms and AJV: validation warnings instead of errors

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv, jsonforms

I have a specific use case in which we use several JSON schemas to create forms using `@jsonforms/core` in combination with `@jsonforms/angular` ([jsonforms.io](https://jsonforms.io)). The validation happens as recommended with `ajv`.

To approach this as generic as possible (I would like to have no custom code per form), I have built separate data and UI schemas for each form. And when posting this to the API (in NestJS), I validate the payload once again with the specific schema for data consistency (also with `ajv`), before saving to the database.

But, for one specific form (and maybe also for future forms), the validation of the values is as follows. It is allowed to post an empty form, but we would like to **recommend / warn the user** that the form hasn't been filled in completely yet. Preferably with a modal. So: the specific fields *are* somewhat required, but not *strictly needed*.

Is there a way in JSON schema / JSON schema forms / AJV to show a warning but allow the form values to pass the validation? Are there levels of error handling, or maybe use strict mode for this?

This is how I create my AJV, both in front-end as back-end (TypeScript):

```js
ajv = createAjv({
  schemaId: 'auto',
  allErrors: true,
  jsonPointers: true,
  errorDataPath: 'property',
});
```

Example of data schema (simplified), JSON:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "group1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "level1": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level2": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level3": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level4": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": []
    },
    "group2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "level1": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level2": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level3": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        },
        "level4": {
          "type": "integer",
          "enum": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": []
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?